# How to Stop a MATLAB Timer Object From The Function's Workspace After It's Executed

Tags: matlab, timer

Say I've got a function that evaluates to:

```
function test_timer()
a = timer ;
set(a, 'executionMode', 'fixedRate','TimerFcn','disp(rand)')
start(a)

end
```

..and I've accidentally left out 'stop(a)' within the function's clause. 
How do you stop the timer object (or all timer objects) from running without closing MATLAB using the command window?

Comment: If this is a duplicate question, please link me to its duplicate. I can't seem to Google for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`timerfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timerfind.html) to find the timers you would like to stop.

Like this:

```
tmr = timer('Name', 'timer1', 'TimerFcn', @(x,y)disp('Timer running'));
start(tmr);
stop(timerfind('Name', 'timer1'));
```

You can basically search any property you can define in timer function.

**EDIT:** You can use the [`delete`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deletetimer.html) function to delete the timers.

Let's create a couple of timers to find and delete them:

```
tmr1=timer('Name', 'timer1', 'Period', 5, 'TimerFcn', @(x,y)disp('Timer 1 running'));
tmr2=timer('Name', 'timer2', 'Period', 5, 'TimerFcn', @(x,y)disp('Timer 2 running'));
start(tmr1);
start(tmr2);
tmrList=timerfind('Period', 5); % Find the timers whose periods are 5 seconds.
stop(tmrList);
timerfind

Timer Object Array

   Index:  ExecutionMode:  Period:  TimerFcn:               Name:
   1       singleShot      5        1x1 function_handle arraytimer1
   2       singleShot      5        1x1 function_handle arraytimer2


delete(tmrList);
timerfind

ans =

     []
```

Comment: It works! My next question is, how can I reset the list of the timer objects without closing the MATLAB window? Currently I've a list of 25 objects, and if the list gets any longer, it's difficult to determine which ones are active and which ones to kill...

Comment: Found a particular way to kill all running timers (including hidden ones) via command: `stop(timerfindall)`.

Comment: @Choe You can use the delete function to clear the timers from memory. I added a code sample.

Comment: of course... `delete`. Why haven't I thought of the obvious.. Thanks!!